# How to integrate epub file in own ebook reader application using ExpressPlay sdk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

I have to integrate epub files in our existing ebook reader application by using ExpressPlay Sdk.
However, I am unable to get solution.
I got some idea by given link : https://www.expressplay.com/ebooks/
but it is still not able to integrate.

Any idea will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @Shital, Is this question still open? I got success in implementation so I can help.

Comment: yes..Still open ..can you tell me how you integrated epub files?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Hello @Shital, 
I've tested the code again and found that its working fine. :)

Comment: @RahulUpadhyay Thank you so much..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to setup proper details while encrypting file. And need to use token for the decryption.

So here are the steps to follow :

**1. Encryption using bento4 packaging tools :** 
(You can find tools here : https://www.bento4.com/downloads/ ) :

- Extract the package to some dir and open Terminal or CMD to that path
- Follow the command

> mp4dcfpackager --method CBC --key
>   CONTENT_KEY:00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff --content-id
>   CONTENT_ID --content-type CONTENT_TYPE
>   INPUT_FILE_PATH OUTPUT_FILE_NAME

Where,

- CONTENT_KEY : content_key from https://admin.expressplay.com/bblicensetoken/
- CONTENT_ID : content_id from https://admin.expressplay.com/bblicensetoken/
- CONTENT_TYPE : for PDF use, application/pdf || for ePUB use application/epub
- INPUT_FILE_PATH : File to be converted with DRM content
- OUTPUT_FILE_PATH : File name after encryption (make file name same as input file name with extension so you can differentiate file type at app side)

**2. Create a Marlin BB License Token (BB Token is used for offline validation):**

Add following parameters from https://admin.expressplay.com/bblicensetoken/ :

- Content ID
- Content Key
- Rights Type : "Buy to Own"
- Output Control Override Id : "urn:marlin:organization:intertrust:wudo"
- Output Control Override Parameter : "ImageContraintLevel"
- Output Control Override Value : "0"
- Wudo Extension = true
- Click on **Get Token**
- Store file to your project

Now, you can get an idea from the samples they provided in SDK that how to use this token file with project.

If you still have any confusion let me know. I've followed the same steps for android so it should work for iOS too.

Thanks.